# Elements and arrows in an abelian category.

Tags: category-theory

Suppose to work in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, so in particular for every objects $A$ and $B$, we have that $Hom(A,B)$ is an abelian group - in particular a set. My questions are:

1. Does it suffice to conclude that $A$ and $B$ are sets?
2. If "yes", does it suffice to conclude that the arrows from $A$ to $B$ are function, in a set-theoretic sense?

I am almost sure that both of the statement are *completely wrong*, but I should be better if I received a proof/disproof (if possible, an example should be perfect!).

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Comment: It's not meaningful to ask whether the objects in a category "are" sets. The meaningful question is whether they *can be interpreted* as sets, or more precisely whether the category admits a faithful functor to $\text{Set}$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category). The key distinction is that interpretations (that is, faithful functors to $\text{Set}$) need not be unique if they exist; they are structures on rather than properties of categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal answer is no, the objects of an abelian category need not be sets, nor do the morphisms need be functions. However, the [Freyd-Mitechell](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Freyd-Mitchell+embedding+theorem) embedding theorem says that an abelian category, and particularly a small one, is not far from being essentially a category of modules over some ring, with morphisms the module homomorphisms. In particular, when dealing with small enough diagrams in an abelian category one can safely pretend one is working with modules.